# shortcode content does not equal same text passed as a string value. preg_match_all returns different results

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, preg-match-all, shortcode

I have a short code that is supposed to use preg_match_all parse content formatted like this:

```
Sex:3,Drugs,4,Violence:1,Rock & Roll,5
```

into labels and number ratings.

The following pattern works when I feed the above into it as a string variable:

```
%([\w&\s]+)[:,\|\/]{1}(\d+)([\|,\|\/]{0,1})%
```

The pattern is smart enough to allow multiple delimiters between values. With single words, it works all the time. However, when I feed the exact same string as the $content value in a shortcode function, the last label, 'Rock & Roll,' is returned as 'Roll'.

Just to be clear, I fed the exact same value as the string variable **$contentX** into preg_match_all and it returned 'Rock & Roll.'

Also when I compare the $content variable to my $contentX variable, using

```
if ($content === $contentX) {

}
```

PHP tells me that the two strings are **not** exactly equal, even though $contentX is an exact copy of the text fed through the shortcode.

Somehow, passing through the shortcode $content variable changes the string in a way that changes the behavior of regular expressions. Is there anything I can do to the $content variable to make it behave the same way as a string value passed directly to preg_match_all?

Here is the code that compares to two.

```
function WTF($atts, $content) {

    $pattern = '%([\w&\s]+)[:,\|\/]{1}(\d+)([\|,\|\/]{0,1})%';

    $conX = 'Sex:3,Drugs,4,Violence:1,Rock & Roll,5';

    preg_match_all($pattern, $content, $xmatch, PREG_SET_ORDER);
    preg_match_all($pattern, $conX, $ymatch, PREG_SET_ORDER);

    $ret = '<pre>' . print_r($xmatch, TRUE);

    $ret .= "\n" . print_r($ymatch, TRUE);

    if ($content === $conX) {
        $ret .= "\n" . 'Match!';
    } else {
        $ret .= "\nNo Match!";
    }
    $ret .= '</pre>';

    return $ret;

}
```

The print_f for the first pass ($content) returns this:

```
Array
(
  [3] => Array
    (
        [0] =>  Roll,5
        [1] =>  Roll
        [2] => 5
        [3] => 
    )

)
```

Here is the print_r() output for $conX is this:

```
Array
(
  [3] => Array
    (
        [0] => Rock & Roll,5
        [1] => Rock & Roll
        [2] => 5
        [3] => 
    )

 )
```

Comment: It makes 0% sense to allow multiple delimiters here. I would use json or serialize to flatten the data. Choosing the right data format is an important design decision. It looks like you failed on that. Even drugs can't help...

Comment: Focusing on the regex: it's horrible, but let's improve it! 1) `{1}` is redundant so remove it 2) `{0,1}` is the same as `?` 3) You don't need to escape those characters in a character class `[:,\|\/]` becomes `[:,|/]` 4) Why are you duplicating characters in `[\|,\|\/]`? Just use `[,|/]`

Comment: Not your core issue, but to complete @HamZa's comment the last part is also irrelevant: ending your regex with something optional has no purpose here (always returns true). So it can overall be reduced to the easier on the eye `([\w&\s]+)[:,|/](\d+)`

Comment: You talk about `$content === $contentX` being false, can you show the code where both these variables are defined/used?

Comment: @hek2mgl, I don't think it makes zero sense to allow multiple delimiters. It makes the shortcode more flexible. But that doesn't answer the question I'm asking.

Comment: @HamZa, I appreciate the help in improving my regex skillset, but none of that really addresses the core issue. Why does the $content var passed through the shortcode function behave differently than the exact same text passed through a declared variable inside the function.

Comment: @Robin, the $content variable comes directly though the Wordpress shortcode api and is passed to a shortcode function:

`function shortcode_func($atts, $content) {}`

This is passed through the function with the shortcode `[shortcode]Sex:3,Drugs,4,Violence:1,Rock & Roll,5[/shortcode]`, while the $contentX variable was declared inside the shortcode function for the purpose of testing: `$contentX = 'Sex:3,Drugs,4,Violence:1,Rock & Roll,5';`

Comment: @Paul If it doesn't answer your question you did not understood my comment.

Comment: @Paul Prove it with a working **reproducable code** and show it to us, in this kind of case it's 99.99999% the fault of the programmer, the rest might be a bug. If php says that `$content === $contentX` is false, then it is most likely false, try to use `var_dump()` and compare the values. Also maybe enabling error reporting might give you some juicy information.

Comment: @hek2mgl, I did understand your comment just fine. It didn't address my question of why a declared variable is different than than the exact same text passed through the $content variable of a shortcode. That is my only question.

Comment: @HamZa, I am not questioning that two variables are not exactly equal. My question is why.

`function WTF($atts, $content) { $pattern = '%([\w&\s]+)[:,\|\/]{1}(\d+)([\|,\|\/]{0,1})%';
 $conX = 'Sex:3,Drugs,4,Violence:1,Rock & Roll,5';
 preg_match_all($pattern, $content, $xmatch, PREG_SET_ORDER);
 preg_match_all($pattern, $conX, $ymatch, PREG_SET_ORDER);
 $ret = '<pre>' . print_r($xmatch, TRUE);
 $ret .= "\n" . print_r($ymatch, TRUE);
 if ($content === $conX) {
  $ret .= "\n" . 'Match!';
 } else {
  $ret .= "\nNo Match!";
 }
 $ret .= '</pre>';
 return $ret;
}
`

Comment: @Paul [I can't reproduce it](https://eval.in/139987)

Comment: Sorry, just a joke. Your last comment looks like you had too much of them all

Comment: @HamZa You have to have one value that contains spaces, like 'Rock and Roll.' That is where I run into a problem.

Comment: Also, I think the problem lies in the Wordpress shortcode API, so unless you can post that code into a Wordpress site, you probably can't reproduce it,.

Comment: @Paul Try to [trim()](http://php.net/trim) the input. As for your regex, [try to split instead of matching](https://eval.in/139992) `array_chunk(preg_split('~[:,]+~', $input), 2);`. I think this is my last input, also I hate WordPress.

Comment: I just figured out that passing the string through the shortcode replaced the '&' character with &#038; explaining why the dump_var was 5 characters longer. I guess that explains the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have to run the $content through the html_entity_decode function. That returns the content to its original form and the preg_match works as expected.